# Video recorded with recordrtc is not playable on ios safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, recordrtc

Using RecordRTC, I recorded the screen with mimetype: `video/webm;codecs=vp9`, but this video is not playable on ios safari/chrome.

I then tried `video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1` but its also not playable. It works fine on windows. Getting no clue what format should work for ios while using recordRTC?